# Problema com variável nula

Tags: c#, .net, nullpointerexception

Estou a desenvolver um software em C# com o *modelo MVVM*, e com o Visual Studio.

É um software para gerir os membros de uma universidade.

Temos que utilizar também uma base de dados, com Code First.

O meu problema, é que me dá o seguinte erro:

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   UniversityMembers.exe but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**Vou assinalar o erro no código em baixo:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static VMUniversityMembers d = new VMUniversityMembers();
    ProjectContext db = d.ProjectContext;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (db)
        {

            var query = (DataContext as VMUniversityMembers).ProjectContext.UniversityMembers.SqlQuery("Select * from UniversityMembers");  **<---- Dá o erro aqui**

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                listView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"VM UniversityMembers" é a View Model entre o Modelo "UniversityMembers" e a interface gráfica:

```
namespace UniversityMembers.ViewModel
{
    class VMUniversityMembers:BaseModel
    {
        private ProjectContext projectContext;
        private UniversityMember selectedMember = null;

        public List<UniversityMember> Members
        {
            get
            {
                return projectContext.UniversityMembers.Include("Position").Include("Sex").ToList();
            }
        }

        public ProjectContext ProjectContext
        {
            get
            {
                return projectContext;
            }
            set
            {
                projectContext = value;
            }

        }
        public UniversityMember SelectedMember
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedMember;
            }

            set
            {
                selectedMember = value;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Método para adicionar alunos 
         */

        internal void Add()
        {
            var unmbm = new UniversityMember();    

            projectContext.UniversityMembers.Add(unmbm);
            this.selectedMember = unmbm;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("UniversityMembers");    

        }
        internal void Cancel()
        {

        }
        /**
         *Método  para guardar a informacao introduzida  
         *
         */
        internal void SaveContext()
        {
            projectContext.SaveChanges();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("UniversityMembers");

        }
        /**
        * Método para eliminar um utilizador seleccionado na lista 
        * 
        */
        internal void Delete()
        {
            projectContext.UniversityMembers.Remove(SelectedMember);
        }    
    }
}
```

E o modelo que uso é o UniversitYMembers:

```
    namespace UniversityMembers.Models
{
    class UniversityMember : Person
    {           
       public string email;
      // public  Position position;
       public string migration;


        public string Email { get { return email; } set { email = value; } }
      //  public Position Position { get { return position; } set { position = value; } }

        public UniversityMember()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

A classe `UniversityMembers` extende na superclass `Person`, com outros atributos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou considerar que `DataContext` é do tipo `VMUniversityMembers`, se não for, tá aí o erro. Parece estar depois.

A propriedade `ProjectContext` não parece estar sendo inicializada em lugar algum, parece que o problema está aí.

`UniversityMembers` certamente não está inicializada, aí também tem erro.

Algumas outras observações:

```
using (db)
```

Isso não funciona, não é assim que usa isso, não vai liberar nada aí, ou pior, vai liberar o que não pode, mas é outro assunto.

Isto:

```
public string email;
public string Email { get { return email; } set { email = value; } }
```

é o mesmo que isto:

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/SimpleSyntax.cs).

O mesmo vale para todas as outras propriedade que fazem algo tão simples e padronizado.

Comment: Obrigado, vou alterar o código, e depois dou algum feedback.
Peço desculpa por alguns erros estúpidos, porque estamos agora a aprender a usar c# e o professor, não explica como deve explicar e ficamos um pouco sem saber o que fazer em caso de erros!

Comment: Se tiver alguma mais específico, eu tento dar uma melhorada.

Comment: muito obrigada, eu estou a fazer passo a passo, com as indicações que me deu, e ja posto o resultado. Obrigado :)